# .Mp4(h264) with framerate:25 video not seekable in Exoplayer

Tags: android, h.264, seekbar, exoplayer

I am using ExoPlayer 2.11.1 and playing a video with codec(h.264 avc) .MP4. Frame rate is 25. Video is playing but the seekbar is issuing everytime i seek the video , it start playing from the start . I am playing this video Link is :https://drive.google.com/open?id=16CJJKU-p6Dwd3WBi8KaVuBJn1y8Os7qi.
Also at the first 19 second there is no duration to be known after that the seekbar is visible with duration total and If I seek the video , Video play again from the start
Please help me I am beginner of Exoplayer .

Comment: if you have ExtractorsFactory enable ConstantBitrateSeeking

Comment: @Hooman I have tried it but no effect there is on video

Comment: I got a solution to change the value of TIMESTAMP_SEARCH_BYTES to be increased must to play the video in tsDurationReader file.